# JSON response date doesnt match

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

Can anyone shed some light on this issue, I am using the code below which is outputting a JSON response from an ajax request

```
    console.log('get_therapist_sessions, response);
    response.forEach(function(index){
      console.log(index);
    });
```

However when i console.log the date is correct, but inspecting the actual object the date is incorrect, what I want is to be able to use the date that appears when I use console.log

[image: output of console]

Comment: do you use .ToJSON in somewhere to convert your date object. It can be a time zone offset difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your objects `start_date` and `end_date` are Date objects which are not string at first.

If you want to convert from Date to String, try `start_date.toString()`and `end_date.toString()`. This is what `console.log()` without telling you.

Comment: makes no difference I am afraid, also tried using `String(index.start_date)`

Comment: What do you mean with no difference ? Do you get an error ? What is the output of `typeof(index.start_date)` ?

Comment: updated code
`response.forEach(function(index){
                    console.log(index);
                    console.log(typeof(index.start_date));
                });`
says that it is a string

Comment: I think you have to share a little more of your code because I cannot help you more with just this :/